# How to ignore a file while using FileSystemWatcher and the events it triggers from modifying/changing the folder it's in?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the FileSystemWatcher to watch a specific subdirectory and log the events to a file. I can ignore the file changes but I can't get around ignoring the changes notified by the folder it is in.  So I get stuck in an infinite loop of the folder it's in being changed, logged to the file, the folder is changed, the changed it logged, etc.  Is there a way to stop this without completely ignoring the folder the file is in?  I can't differentiate between a change made to the folder from a different file or the file used for logging changes.  For example, if I have a folder named "Stuff" and the files "log.txt" and  "work.txt", if I modify "work.txt" then I will get a notification that "work.txt" changed, and "Stuff" changed, and "log.txt" which will then modify "Stuff" which will be logged etc.

Comment: Can you also post the code that you already made?

Comment: So you're logging to a file inside a folder that a FileSystemWatcher is watching, and every time you write a log entry, it triggers the FSW to raise an event? Surely, the simplest thing is to keep the log file outside of the folder? Th next simplest thing (given that FSW filters are inclusive) is to exclude any events relating to the log file itself and also any events relating to the directory of the log file...

Comment: I have to be able to watch any directory.  So the path is given by the user, it isn't a matter of me simply moving the file.

Comment: Why are you not able to differentiate between changes in your logfile and changes in other files? The `FileSystemEventArgs` you get with the `OnChanged` handler contains the filename which triggered the event. Modifiying a file within a folder will trigger only one event, not one for the file and one for the folder.

Comment: Because it changes the folder it is in as well, it does not state whether the folder change was made from the log file or some other file/subdirectory. If I change a file, a notification is made that the file was changed as well as the folder it is in.  If I update the log file a change notification that the folder it is in gets triggered, which gets logged, which changes the folder it is in etc.  I cannot differentiate between what files are causing the folder change notification especially if there are multiple changes going on at one time.

Comment: @user13985180 How did you define your watcher? It doesn't do that for me. Although it might be possible that writing to a file may trigger *two* `Changed` events for that file, instead of only one ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140507-00/?p=1053 ). But editing a file `c:\somefolder\somefile.txt` within a folder `c:\somefolder` does only trigger events for `c:\somefolder\somefile.txt` and not for `c:\somefolder`

Comment: If I watch c:\somefolder and edit c:\somefolder\somefile.txt then only one event is triggered. But if I watch c:\somefolder and have c:\somefolder\somefolder2\somefile.txt and c:\somefolder\somefolder2\log.txt I will get a notification that somefile.txt changed AND somefolder2 changed (due to somefile.txt being changed and log.txt changed when it's being written to) which will cause the infinite change/write loop.

Comment: Again, show how you define your watcher. It doesn't do that for me either. I only get events for the file I actually changed. Also if the file is in a subfolder of the watched folder